# Captcha doesn't come out in my multiform webform

Tags: captcha

I have a multiform webform with 3 steps. Why can't I seem to get the CAPTCHA to appear at the end of the form, even when I've already checked *Add CAPTCHA administration links to forms*? Am I missing anything?

I am using Drupal 7 and Captcha 7.x-1.0-alpha3.

Answer (score 2):

admin forms is not the same as webforms. You need to manually add the webform to the captcha settings.

Go to admin/config/people/captcha/captcha/settings in the blank text box under "Form Protection" enter the form_id of the webform and save the configuration. Go to the webform page and you should be able to see the captcha there.

To quickly find the form_id of the webform, take the node id and append it to "webform_client_form_", for example if the node id is 3 your webform form_id will be "webform_client_form_3". If this is not your case, you can always use firebug to inspect the hidden form_id field.

Comment: This doesn't work for me since my webform has 3 steps (2 page breaks). By doing what you just said, the end of each pagebreak gets marked with its own captcha which is crazy. In total, I have *3 captchas for each step* when all I want is **one captcha placed at the end of the form.**

Comment: interesting. I suppose you could put on a hidden captcha http://drupal.org/project/hidden_captcha Much more appealing than having your users fill out a captcha, in the first place. On a side note, if this is a three step webform (and if there are any required or validated fields) then you probably won't need to put a captcha on it. A bot might not be able to get past the first page, let alone 3.

Comment: Really? Bots can't get past a multiform webform? As in really, really? If what you're saying is true then I have no need for captcha anymore...but seriously they can't?

Comment: All I am saying is that bots generally have a difficult time getting past any validation on a page (e.g. email or phone formatting are just basic examples). However, I am not saying it is full proof. Nothing is. If your form has a number of fields that require validation, and the form is validated upon each pressing of "Next Step", then it is highly unlikely they would make it to the third page and/or final submission. From a usability perspective, anytime you can remove steps for an end-user, your more likely to the see a better conversion rate.

Comment: I see, I'll shorten my form to 2 steps then.

Comment: I was really trying to figure out how to even add a webform to captcha, thanks!